# REACT using MAP or forEach doesn't show nothing

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, foreach, render

I'm new with React and I'm here asking for help. The render method won't render anything, no error, nothing to see where I mess up. I'm sure "recetas" has an array of items in there because I check it, but the map doesn't go through the array and I don't understand why. I know what maybe it's because of the "await" and "async" in the function but that shouldn't be a problem. I'm sure the solution is very easy but I can't see it!

---

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Favoritas extends React.Component{
  state = {
    recetas: []
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
     const req= await fetch('https://scrap-cook-servicio-web.herokuapp.com/recetas');
     const res= await req.json();
     this.setState({recetas: res.message});  
 }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        {this.state.recetas.map((receta, i) => {
            <div className="mt-5 max-w-md mx-auto bg-white rounded-xl shadow-md overflow-hidden md:max-w-2xl">
              <div className="md:flex">
                <div className="md:flex-shrink-0">
                  <img className="h-48 w-full object-cover md:w-48" src="/favicon.ico" alt="Man looking at item at a store"/>
                </div>
                <div className="p-8">
                  <div className="uppercase tracking-wide text-sm text-indigo-500 font-semibold">TYPE</div>
                  <a href="#" className="block mt-1 text-lg leading-tight font-medium text-black hover:underline">TITLE</a>
                  <p className="mt-2 text-gray-500">DESCRIPTION</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        })
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I hope you can help me and I'll appreciate any help!

Comment: You're not returning anything from your `map` callback function

Comment: Javier do `{this.state.recetas.map((receta, i) => (` Difference is using `(` instead of `{` this would return your markup in itself or add return statement `{this.state.recetas.map((receta, i) => { return ( <div className="mt `

Answer (score 1):

Your `map` function is a JSX block that is not being returned. You have two options of doing this.

```js
render() {
    return(
      <div>
        {this.state.recetas.map((receta, i) => (
            <div key={receta.id}>...</div>
          ))
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
```

or

```js
render() {
    return(
      <div>
        {this.state.recetas.map((receta, i) => {
            return (
              <div key={receta.id}>...</div>
            )
          })}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Just make sure your JSX has a unique `key` wrapped around the outer element. I'm making an assumption here that each `receta` has an id, so you may need to update this on your end.